# Mostrar carga al subir archivos al input

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de mostrar con un `console.log` el porcentaje de subida de los archivos que seleccione.

Hasta ahora solo me salía el nombre y el tamaño del archivo en el `p#demo`, pero cuando añadí el `addEventListener('progress', (event)=>{...}` dejaron de salirme los resultados que obtenía hasta ahora.

El caso es que el `progress` no se dispara. ¿Por qué puede ser?

```js
function myFunction(){
  let x = document.getElementById("myFile");
  let peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
  let txt = "";
  
  if ('files' in x) {
    if (x.files.length == 0) {
      txt = "Select one or more files.";
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
        //comienza iteracion
        peticion.addEventListener("progress", (event)=>{
            let porcentaje = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            console.log(porcentaje);

            txt += "<br><strong>" + (i+1) + ". file</strong><br>";
            var file = x.files[i];

            if ('name' in file) {
            txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
            }

            if ('size' in file) {
            txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes <br>";
            } 
        });
        //finaliza iteracion
      }
    }
  } 
  else {
    if (x.value == "") {
      txt += "Select one or more files.";
    } else {
      txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
      txt  += "<br>The path of the selected file: " + x.value;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" onchange="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**[EDIT]**

Ya me salen los resultados a excepción del evento progress que no comienza:

```
function myFunction(){
  var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
  var txt = "";
  
  if ('files' in x) {
    if (x.files.length == 0) {
      txt = "Select one or more files.";
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
        let peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();

        txt += "<br><strong>" + (i+1) + ". file</strong><br>";
        var file = x.files[i];
        if ('name' in file) {
          txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
        }
        if ('size' in file) {
            console.log(file.charge);
          txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes";
        }

        peticion.addEventListener("progress", (event) => {
            let porcentaje = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);

            console.log(porcentaje+'%');
            txt += "loading: "+porcentaje + "%<br>";
        });

      }
    }
  } 
  else {
    if (x.value == "") {
      txt += "Select one or more files.";
    } else {
      txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
      txt  += "<br>The path of the selected file: " + x.value;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se dispara el evento `progress` porque estás creando la petición, pero no la ejecutas. Vas a necesitar esto:

- Crear un objeto [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)
- [Agregar el archivo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#creating_a_formdata_object_from_scratch) al objeto del paso anterior
- Inicializar la petición con [peticion.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open), enviando como parámetros el método de proceso (POST) y la URL
- Procesar con [peticion.send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)
- Seguramente querrás saber el resultado de la petición, por lo que es necesario escuchar otro evento, [onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange)

De acuerdo a como sugieren en [este ejemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/progress_event), es conveniente escuchar varios eventos para mostrar progreso desde el inicio.

```
// Definir url para envío, suponiendo que usas PHP
let url = 'ruta/subir_ajax.php';

// Función para analizar progreso en varios eventos
function progressHandler(e) {
    let porcentaje = parseInt(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
    console.log('Evento: ' + e.type + ' ' + porcentaje + '%');
}
// Función para eventos error y abort
function errorHandler(e) {
    console.log('Error subiendo archivo: ' + e.type);
}

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myFile");
  var txt = "";
  
  if ('files' in x) {
    if (x.files.length == 0) {
      txt = "Select one or more files.";
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
        let peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();

        txt += "<br><strong>" + (i+1) + ". file</strong><br>";
        let file = x.files[i];
        if ('name' in file) {
          txt += "name: " + file.name + "<br>";
        }
        if ('size' in file) {
            console.log(file.charge);
          txt += "size: " + file.size + " bytes";
        }

        // Escuchar eventos
        peticion.addEventListener("loadstart", progressHandler);
        peticion.addEventListener("load", progressHandler);
        peticion.addEventListener("loadend", progressHandler);
        peticion.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler);
        peticion.addEventListener("error", errorHandler);
        peticion.addEventListener("abort", errorHandler);

        // Crear objeto FormData
        let data = new FormData();
        // Agregar archivo
        data.append('file', file);

        // Verificar que el objeto es correcto
        console.log(...data);

        // Inicializar petición
        peticion.open('POST', url);
        // Escuchar cambios de estado
        peticion.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(peticion.readyState == 4) {
                // Se completó la petición, hay que analizar el resultado
                if(peticion.status == 200) {
                    // El archivo se subió correctamente
                    // Obtener respuesta del servidor
                    let resp = peticion.responseText;
                    console.log(resp);
                } else {
                    console.log('Ocurrió un error subiendo el archivo');
                }
            }
        };
        // Ejecutar petición, enviando archivo
        peticion.send(data);
      }
    }
  } 
  else {
    if (x.value == "") {
      txt += "Select one or more files.";
    } else {
      txt += "The files property is not supported by your browser!";
      txt  += "<br>The path of the selected file: " + x.value;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Si no se muestra progreso y "brinca" a 100%, seguramente estás subiendo archivos pequeños, que no requieren varios pasos para completarse o se suben muy rápido. Prueba el [resultado del ejemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/progress_event#result):

> loadstart: 0 bytes transferred
> progress: 131072 bytes transferred
> progress: 541460 bytes transferred
> load: 541460 bytes transferred
> loadend: 541460 bytes transferred

Un archivo de aproximadamente 530kb mostró solo dos pasos del progreso, aunque en este caso es descarga, pero funciona igual al subir.

No deberías obtener `NaN` al realizar los cálculos, porque las [propiedades](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent#properties) *loaded* y *total* son de tipo entero.

### Del lado del servidor

En PHP recibes el archivo en `$_FILES['file']` y, en caso de no obtener lo esperado, incluye `var_dump($_FILES);` para ver lo que estás recibiendo.

Comment: Vale, ya hice los cambios que me pusiste, pero sigo teniendo dos pequeños problemas. En la línea para obtener el porcentaje, no me lo saca hasta que haya sido completado, a parte, me saca un NaN por consola. Y en el subir_ajax.php me sale un undefined, pero será mas normal porque no controlo casi nada de php y lo tendré seguramente mal, eso lo iré corrigiendo poco a pco

Comment: @AQMR, actualicé la respuesta con base en un ejemplo de la documentación de Mozilla.

Comment: Justo, había probado de otra manera pero me servía de forma individual al subir los archivos, creo que juntaré ambas cosas para hacer multi subidas, porque sino...